# Getline not getting input

Tags: c++

```
    string input;
    string input2;
printf("What is your name?\n-->");
getline(cin, input);
std::string nameObj = "{ \"name\": " + '"' + input + '"' + " }";
printf("What do you want to send?\n-->");
getline(cin, input2);
std::string jsonObj = "{ \"content\": " + '"' + input2 + '"' + ", \"tts\": true }";
```

It asks for the input, but then it doesn't do anything with it. I need it to put it in for input2 and input, but it doesn't.

Comment: You really ought to check the stream state after reading and writing to see if the operation failed and "broke" the stream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is almost correct, the only thing which might not do what you want is adding `char` to `char*` as you do in the JSON construction. Write it like this:

```
string input;
string input2;
printf("What is your name?\n-->");
getline(cin, input);
std::string nameObj = "{ \"name\": \"" + input + "\" }";
cout << nameObj << endl;
printf("What do you want to send?\n-->");
getline(cin, input2);
std::string jsonObj = "{ \"content\": \"" + input2 + "\", \"tts\": true }";
cout << jsonObj << endl;
```

http://ideone.com/zY1LFg

`char`s are basically numbers, so you inadvertently did pointer arithmetic instead of concatenating strings and chars. C++'s built-in types are really rather primitive, e.g. you also can't concatenate raw `char*`s; to do that, you always need to wrap them in `std::string("...")`.

Instead of concatenating, you could look into [`stringstream`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/stringstream/) to build your JSON strings while avoiding the copying which is caused by repeatedly concatenating strings.

You should also check if the `cin` stream is ok after reading from it by doing `if (!cin.good()) { /* handle error */ }`. Error handling usually involves clearing the stream's state with `cin.clear()`.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: If this helped you, please upvote and accept this as an answer ;)

Comment: I clicked the green checkmark, but I can't leave an upvote because not enough rep or something.

Answer (score -1):

first include using namespace std; below header files
and then go here and see the code
https://justpaste.it/14aam